# Running time-critical executable (CPU+GPU) I receive huge time divergence among execution runtimes

Tags: cpu, gpu, benchmarks, process-priority

Under Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS I am running a multithreading application that is using both CPUs and GPU. My question is that among sequencing identical runs, I get huge time divergence among execution runtimes (benchmarks). I checked the processes running in the background which seems very normal and the CPU idle time is almost 99%.

For example

1st Run: 573 secs
2nd Run: 750 secs
3rd Run: 986 secs

I tried to run the application with lower priority using `nice -n15` but I didn't see any differences.

So, 1) how can I explain this phenomenon? and 2)how to set the application to Real-time priority?

Regards,

Comment: @guiverc yes Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: This is probably related to your CPU/GPU temps. A possible explanation is: in the first run your CPU/GPU started near ambient and had the ability to boost to max turbo for a decent time then trottled due to heat. In the second run maybe the CPU/GPU were already hot from the first run hence it didn't turbo. The third one maybe had even worse throttling. It is actually hard to determine what is the cause without more information. What is your app doing? Only CPU/GPU bound or it accesses the disk frequently? Is it processing the same data?

Comment: yes they processing the same data and also using disk frequently (video encoding). GPU load is about 60%

Comment: I will re-run the tests with `chrt -f 99` command and check again.

Comment: Assuming you have an SSD, SSDs (Non SLC ones) use SLC cache to cover for the slower write speed of TLC and QLC cells. Maybe you are exhasting your SLC write cache and writing to the slower TLC cells. Run your app while monitoring CPU/GPU load, frequency, temps and disk bandwidth.

Comment: thanx, I will be monitoring the statistics. SSD is the primary disk used only for boot. The application read/write IOs are on a secondary mechanical HD.